# Is this node.js declaration code the node.js way or can it be improved by using fewer commas and broken up into more lines?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just migrated from python to node.js. I find that the syntax of this declaration code in node.js weird coming from a python background. Why does it have so many commas? Is it possible to rewrite it using fewer commas and break up into more lines? Is such a syntax common in node.js? For a python person, the code looks harder to read.

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs = require('fs'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    connectionsArray = [],
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
      database: 'dbSen',
      port: 3306
    }),
    POLLING_INTERVAL = 1000,
    pollingTimer;
```

Comment: It's one long variable statement that declares 8 variables. You could break it into single statements, but nearly all the commas will become semicolons and you'll have 7 more `var`s.

Comment: But I have to put `var` in front of every line, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connectionsArray = [];
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'dbSen',
    port: 3306
});
var POLLING_INTERVAL = 1000;
var pollingTimer;
```

The comma simply extends the `var` keyword onto the next line. It is indeed common practice though I agree that it makes code harder to read.

The reason you will see this pattern is because people prefer not to write the `var` keyword several times and not using the `var` keyword:

```
app = require('http').createServer(handler);
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

will make the variables global or raise a `ReferenceError` if you are running in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

You might find [the mdn page on the var keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) useful

Comment: Thanks. I think javascript programmers should try to learn to write like python folks to make the code more readable.

Comment: @user768421—not everyone uses the style in the OP. It's not usually used with such a mixed bag of assignments, especially putting an object literal in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

One of the quirks of JavaScript is the way variables are created. If you don't use the `var` keyword, the variable will leak to the global scope. Take a look at the following:

```
function foo() {
  var x = 5; // local variable
  y = 10; // this leaks to the global scope!
}
```

Using a comma-separated variable declaration is just a short-hand way of writing numerous `var` statements. So doing something like this:

```
var a = 10,
    b = 20,
    c = 30,
    d = 40;
```

is the same as doing this:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
var c = 30;
var d = 40;
```

And to answer your question, yes, this syntax is common in Node, and in JavaScript in general.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses the var pattern declaration. After your first declaration, you can add multiple declarations separated with commas without repeating the var keyword.